# Склонение текста с помощью i18n

Tags: typescript, angular

подскажите, как просклонять текст с помощью plural из i18n. Так как вывод текста осуществляется не из шаблона, а из компонента `component.ts`, нет понимания как применить в данном случае plural

```
import {
  TranslateService
} from '@ngx-translate/core';

constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {}

get wrongMessagePlural(): string {
  const message = '{this.count, plural,' +
    ' =1 {{{this.count}} элемент}' +
    'few {{{this.count}} элемента}' +
    'other {{{this.count}} элементов' +
    '}';
  return `${message}`;
}

this.snackBarService.show({
  message: `Допустимо ${this.count} ${this.wrongMessagePlural}`
});
```

если бы вывод текста осуществлялся в шаблоне, то выглядело бы следующим образом:

```
<div i18n=""> 
({this.count, plural,
=1 {{{this.count}} элемент}
few {{{this.count}} элемента} 
other {{{this.count}} элементов} })
</div>
```

в документации библиотеки есть [пример](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) использования, но не удается его применить в своем коде.

Comment: @Podushkoved указывайте, пожалуйста, осмысленную причину правки

Answer (score 1):

В Angular уже есть встроенный [I18nPluralPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/I18nPluralPipe)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'i18n-plural-pipe',
  template: `<div>{{ messages.length | i18nPlural: messageMapping }}</div>`
})
export class I18nPluralPipeComponent {
  messages: any[] = ['Message 1'];
  messageMapping: {
    zero: 'No messages.',
    one: 'One message.',
    other: '# messages.'
  };
}
```

```html
<div>{{ messages.length | i18nPlural: messageMapping }}</div>
```

Если же есть необходимость использовать данный код в `component.ts` файле, то нужно просто инжектировать `pipe` как сервис и вызвать метод `.transform()`.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'i18n-plural-pipe',
  template: `<div>{{ message }}</div>`
})
export class I18nPluralPipeComponent {

  message: string = '';
  messages: any[] = ['Message 1'];
  messageMapping: {zero: 'No messages.', one: 'One message.', other: '# messages.'};

  constructor(private readonly i18nPluralPipe: I18nPluralPipe) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message = this.i18nPluralPipe.transform(messages.length, messageMapping);
  }

}
```

```html
<div>{{ text }}</div>
```